# Optimal way to get all consecutive substrings for a string

Tags: performance, time

Given a string: a = "1234567891234567891234567". What's the best way to check for each of the substring ["1","12","123", "1234", etc, "123...7"] (note that only substrings starts at 0, so no "23","234" in the list) on a function f().

I have two proposed methods. Seems like the first one is faster but not sure if it is the optimal one.

1. Building up string and check on the way.

```
    b=""    
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        b=b+a[i]
        f(b)
```

2. Use list comprehension.

```
for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
    b = ''.join([a[j] for j in range(0,i)])
    f(b)
```

I'm asking this because this is a small part of a bigger problem I'm doing, where you have a long string and for each position/char, you check the window of 1,2,3,4..,n character substring starting at that position.

Comment: What about: "23", "34", "234567" and etc ?

Comment: no, you don't have to. Only substrings start at position 0.

Comment: How would you define the "optimal one"?

Comment: optimal one for my bigger problem stated above @nico

Comment: And how is "optimal" defined? Fast execution? Low memory usage? Why not run benchmarks on both versions and compare them?

Comment: you can also: `["".join(a[0:x]) for x in range(len(a))]`

Comment: Oh my bad! I mean time complexity. I already tried both and the first one is faster but wondering if there are even better way of doing it.

Comment: @NirAlfasi, I checked, its better than the second method but still slower than the first one. good one tho!

Comment: @kaith2000 I recommend learning how to use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for micro-benchmarking such as this one.